# Machine Learning books for CS (non-statistician) grad student

Tags: machine-learning, references

What books on machine learning are recommended for a CS graduate student without a huge background in statistics?

I do have some background in ML (and of course linear algebra, probability, etc.) but not really a great/firm background in statistics.

I saw a lot of recommendations for:

1. PRML:  **Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning** by Bishop.
2. ESL:  **Elements of statistical Learning** by Hastie et al.
3. MLaPP: **Machine Learning - a Probabilistic Perspective** by Murphy.

Which ML book is recommended for a grad student with my background?
I see MLaPP is pretty new but seems to include a lot of topics including deep learning etc. - I'd love to know what did someone who read it though of it.

Comment: I don't really see anything terribly distinct about your background. There are a lot of threads on this topic already. Try searching the site & reading some of the [existing threads](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references+machine-learning?sort=votes&pageSize=30).

Comment: **ESL**. Or, if you feel a little rusty re: Math, try their **ISLR** book.